# Detecting changes in object values in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form that displays some data (user details) based on a property, and I want to display a simple "unsaved changes detected" warning if the inner property values are changed.

Like if the `user.firstName` gets changed and it's different from the original value, I want to display the warning.

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <label for="first-name" class="form-label">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name" 
         name="first-name" placeholder="First Name" [(ngModel)]="user.firstName">
</div>
```

```js
user: User;
originalUser: User;

constructor(private actRoute: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UserService) {
  this.user = new User();
  this.originalUser = new User();
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    let userId = this.actRoute.snapshot.parent?.params.id;

    if (!userId || userId === 'new') {
      this.isLoading = false;
      return;
    }

    this.userService.get(userId).subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this.originalUser = user;
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

How can I detect changes in the object values in real time in Angular 12?

I thought about storing the original object value in another property and comparing later.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way using your approach will be

```
// this.userFormChangeEvent is form change event
areEqual$ = this.userFormChangeEvent.pipe(map(user => isEqual(user, originalUser)))

// Save form action
userSaved(newUser) {
    this.userService.set(newUser).subscribe(() => {
        this.originalUser = newUser;
    })
}
```

Then you can use sth like `areEqual$ | async` on element in template or add async validator to Your user form

Comment: I ended up using a form and hooking up the form.valueChanges event.

Comment: Yeah so basically the same thing as I understand :)